# Frozen, mouse still moves

Tags: xfce, crash

I'm somewhat of a Ubuntu novice so please be kind...

Recently I've regularly been experiencing an issue when I am accessing files on a mounted NTFS external hard drive where the system appears frozen, but the mouse still moves and clock reflects time when frozen.  I use Ubuntu Studio with XFCE. This often happens while trying to copy or upload large files, and it appears that the operate is still active while frozen. I am only able to "clear" this issue with REISUB. 
Any suggestions on how to diagnosis and resolve this problem?

**Edit:**

`free -h`

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.9G        2.7G        375M          9G         12G
Swap:           18G          0B         18G
```

`sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`

```
vm.swappiness = 10
UUID=5f3f491a-3320-4f92-b1fe-8f52926f0209 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Flag me via a comment when you have it (not in the edit please).

Comment: @heynnema 
vm.swappiness = 10
UUID=5f3f491a-3320-4f92-b1fe-8f52926f0209   none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: Temporarily use this... in `terminal` type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=60`, and retest. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema  so far so good, I have not experienced the same issue as of yet

Comment: Let me put together a formal answer that shows you how to make the change permanent. Maybe you can accept it for me by clicking the checkmark and up-arrows icons that appear to the left of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

RAM is used to hold your active working applications. Any unused RAM is used as a disk/file buffer/cache. By setting vm.swappiness=10, you reduce swapping, but you potentially also reduce this disk/file buffer/cache space that is used for large file copies.

Since we tried `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=60`, that seemed to work for you.

To set vm.swappiness=60 permanently, do it this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`